# stylelint ignoreFiles not working includes the ignored files paths always

Tags: reactjs, stylelint

In the `stylelint` config file, I have added the `ignoreFiles` array. but on `pre-commit` it's throwing the error from `ignored file path`.

here is my `stylelint.config.cjs`:

```
/*eslint-env node*/

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard',
    'stylelint-config-css-modules',
    'stylelint-config-prettier',
    'stylelint-config-standard-scss',
    'stylelint-config-recommended-scss',
  ],
  plugins: ['stylelint-scss'],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: [
          'tailwind',
          'apply',
          'screen',
          'variants',
          'responsive',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'no-duplicate-selectors': null,
    'no-missing-end-of-source-newline': null,
    'no-empty-source': null,
    'rule-empty-line-before': null,
    'comment-empty-line-before': null,
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': null,
    'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
    'no-descending-specificity': null,
    'string-no-newline': null,
    'selector-max-universal': 1,
    'selector-class-pattern': '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$',
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-before': 'never',
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-after': 'always',
    'scss/dollar-variable-no-missing-interpolation': true,
    'scss/dollar-variable-pattern': /^[a-z]+$/,
    'scss/double-slash-comment-whitespace-inside': 'always',
    'scss/operator-no-newline-before': true,
    'scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector': true,
    'scss/at-rule-no-unknown': null,
  },
  ignoreFiles: ['node_modules/**/*.css', 'dist/**/*.css', 'coverage/**/*.css'],
};
```

when run the pre-commit hook, getting error under the coverage, dist folder.
here is my `package.json`:

```
    {
  "name": "store-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test",
    "test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom",
    "test:unit:coverage": "vitest run --coverage --environment jsdom",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.cjs --write ./**/src/**/*.{css,scss,ts,tsx}",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --config ./prettier.config.cjs --check ./**/src/**/*.{css,scss,ts,tsx}`",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js, .jsx, .cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "stylelint": "npx stylelint \"./**/*.{css,scss,sass}\" --config \"./stylelint.config.cjs\"",
    "stylint:fix": "npm run stylelint --  --fix"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/react": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/vite": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.6.3",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-c8": "~0.25.8",
    "@vitest/ui": "^0.25.8",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.13",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vitest-globals": "^1.3.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jsdom": "~20.0.3",
    "npm": "^9.5.0",
    "nx": "^15.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-extend": "^1.0.5",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.4",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.0.1",
    "postcss-reporter": "^7.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.16.1",
    "stylelint-config-css-modules": "^4.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.5",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^9.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "8.00",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^29.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^6.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2",
    "vite": "^4.0.1",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "~1.7.1",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.2",
    "vitest": "^0.25.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./**/src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "npx nx lint",
    "./**/src/*.{css,scss,sass}": "npm run stylelint",
    "./**/src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": "prettier -w -u"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you just need turn-on your Stylelint plugin in VSCode. Without this action files ignoring not working.

Comment: it is better to put this as a comment not an answer.